# Me. in generic requery function fails

Tags: ms-access, vba

In an MS Access form that has several buttons (used to add/edit/delete data) with VBA code behind them the code at the end of each button's Subroutine refreshes the screen so the user sees the last record they were on prior to clicking the button.  Here is a sample of requery code for one of the buttons:

```vba
Dim rst As Recordset, RecordToView As String
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
RecordToView = CStr(ProducerID)
Me.Requery
rst.FindFirst "ProducerID = " & RecordToView
Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
rst.Close
```

This code, or a similar version, is currently repeated for all buttons on the form.  Here is an attempt to create a generic function so this redundant code can be eliminated:

```vba
Public Function RefreshScreen(Field As String, ByVal RecordToView As String)
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    Me.Requery
    rst.FindFirst Field & " = " & RecordToView
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    rst.Close
End Function
```

And called like so:

```vba
Call RefreshScreen("ProducerID", ProducerID)
```

However, it gives a "Compile error: Invalid use of Me keyword" message when it hits Me.RecordsetClone in the generic function.  What modifications need to be made to the generic function to get it to work?

Comment: Me is the simplified version of the the current object you are dealing with, so instead of writing `Forms!FormName.Form.RecordsetClone`, in the form you simply use `Me.RecordsetClone`. Howver if you are outside the Form, as you are in the generic function it needs to be explicitly declared which Form you are trying to access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the procedure's declaration to expect a reference to the calling form.

```vb
Public Function RefreshScreen(ByRef frm As Form, ByVal fld As String, ByVal RecordToView As String)
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = frm.RecordsetClone
    frm.Requery
    rst.FindFirst fld & " = " & RecordToView
    frm.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    rst.Close
End Function
```

(As a side note, since you're not returning a value from that function, it could be a subroutine instead.  But this should not matter here.)

Then include `Me` when you call the procedure.

```vb
Call RefreshScreen(Me, "ProducerID", ProducerID)
```

I was surprised by the comment which states that `Call()` is obsolete in VBA.  I'd never heard that before, but you can call the procedure without it:

```vb
RefreshScreen Me, "ProducerID", ProducerID
```

Comment: What made you choose `ByRef`/`ByVal` for these parameters the way you did?

Comment: `ByRef` for an object reference.  `ByVal` for simple variables whose values won't be altered by the procedure.

Comment: I guess I'm asking, since `ByRef` is the default why specify anything at all? It seems to work with or without the qualifiers.

Comment: Yes, I add `ByRef` *explicitly* because ... um ... well, that's the habit I developed 10 years ago.  :-)  Thanks for correcting that `Me` error in me answer.

Comment: Made one small edit to the code and that was to change `Me.RecordsetClone` to `frm.RecordsetClone`.  Your solution works like a dream.  Also, what is the importance of including `DAO.` in this line `Dim rst AS DAO.Recordset`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed `Me.RecordsetClone`.  I use `DAO.Recordset` to distinguish it from an `ADODB.Recordset`.  If you have references set for both DAO and ADO, and ADO has the higher precedence, `Dim rst AS Recordset` would get you an `ADODB.Recordset`.  So I always qualify the recordset type to limit confusion.

Comment: Fair enough. And NP about the edit. Looks like the OP figured it out, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do like this:

```
Public Function RefreshScreen( _
    ByRef FormObject As Form, _
    Byval FieldName As String, _
    ByVal RecordToView As Long)

    Dim rst As Recordset

    FormObject.Requery
    Set rst = FormObject.RecordsetClone
    If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rst.FindFirst FieldName & " = " & RecordToView & ""
        If Not rst.NoMatch Then
            FormObject.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
        End If
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

Then:

```
RefreshScreen Me, "ProducerID", ProducerID
```